# Closing/Removing your own questions - standard process?

Tags: discussion

If I ask a question but then I want to "delete" my question, should I simply delete it or should I close it? Or is there another method? (What is the "best" thing to do?)

Comment: There is a "Delete" link on the left hand side, lined up with your signature block. But you can't delete your own question under many circumstances, so it won't always show up.

Comment: @Seraph Closing and removing a question are too different things. You asked it in your title but not in the body... Are you asking for that too?

Comment: Yes sorry, my question should really read: If I want to "delete" my question, should I straight delete it? Or should I close it? Or is there another method my n00bness does not know about. P.S. Thanks for the quick replies!

Comment: You can delete it, so long as the software allows it (some questions, such as questions with answers that have upvotes, are not eligible for OP deletion).

Comment: Better not to delete it.  It isn't hurting anybody, but deleting lots of your questions can hurt you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be very, very careful deleting your own questions.  Excessive deletions can cause you to be question banned.

If you subsequently found the answer to your question, then **post it** for future visitors to see, rather than deleting the whole question.

If you have the urge to delete a whole lot of your questions, then that's likely a sign that there are deeper problems.

Comment: _'then that's likely a sign that there are deeper problems_' - Or that you've learned a lot since. I don't dig this whole scaremongering when it comes to deleting; the banning should be exceptional, and not a concern of a 'legitimate' user.

Comment: @Mr.Disappointment - true, but I'm not the one who created the question ban.  I've seen **good** users question banned on Meta before, and I'm trying to prevent that OP

Comment: I know, and understand your position. I'm just sayin'.